# Angular валидация

Tags: angularjs

хочу сделать форму с валидацией разных полей: даты, времени, нецелого числа. причем валидны 1,23 \ 1.23 \ 123

```js
var app = angular.module('HelloHabr', []);

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
app
  .controller('userController', function($scope) {
    $scope.mimimi = null;
  })
  .directive('mimimi', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('mimimi', false);
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(mimimi) {
          mimimi = (mimimi.replace(',', "."));
          if (isNumeric(mimimi)) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('mimimi', true);
            return mimimi;
          } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('mimimi', false);
            return undefined;
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
input.ng-valid {
  background-color: #81F7F3;
}
input.ng-invalid {
  background-color: #F78181;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="HelloHabr">
  <form name="userForm">
    <div ng-controller="userController">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="LovelyMimimi" ng-model="mimimi" mimimi/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

но это один инпут, и что делать дальше не очень понимаю

```
   <input class="form-control" type="date" name="2nd" ng-model="lol" required lol/> 
   <input class="form-control" type="time" name="3hd" ng-model="time" required time/>
```

несостоятельны, ибо не валидируют

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: непонятен вопрос. Если добавить эту директиву к другим инпутам - от будет не один инпут

Comment: а как добавить директиву для даты dddd-mm-yy или для времени h24:mm:ss

Comment: можно просто воспользоваться `input type="date"`, `input type="time"`

Comment: кроме того ничего не мешает сделать еще две директивы по аналоги с уже приведенной, но вместо `IsNumeric` использовать `IsDate` и `IsTime`

Comment: а в контексте директивы. еще одну подключать?

Comment: не совсем понимаю что именно должно получиться в итоге? в **один** инпут можно ввести либо дату, либо число, либо время? или в один инпут только дату, в другой только число и т.д.?

Comment: да форма с несколькими инпутами. причем я могу определить как валидировать. на каждый инпут своя директива получается?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38612/discussion-between-grundy-and-des1roer).

Comment: @des1roer создавай единые API методы для своего приложения, чтобы использовать их не однократно. Конечно лучше создать для каждого типа свою директиву и валидацию

Comment: Чем же вас ng-pattern не устраивает?

Comment: @fedornabilkin, зачем регулярки если есть встроенные типы у инпутов? :)

Comment: _несостоятельны, ибо не валидируют_ - непонятно для какого кода предоставлена картинка, если для html выше, то там используются уже кастомные директивы `lol`, `time` - поэтому скорее всего ошибка в них. Также стоит указать браузер в котором пробуете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в черновом варианте

```
        <div ng-app="HelloHabr">
            <form name="userForm">
                <div ng-controller="userController">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="1st" ng-model="mimimi" mimimi/>  
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="2nd" ng-model="lol"  lol/> 
                    <input class="form-control" type="time" name="3hd" ng-model="time" required time/>  
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <style>                  
                input.ng-valid {
                    background-color: #81F7F3;
                }
                input.ng-invalid {
                    background-color: #F78181;
                }
            </style>
        </div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('HelloHabr', []);

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function isValidDate(dateString) {
    var arr = dateString.split('-');
    if (arr[0].length == 4 && arr[1] >= 1 && arr[1] <= 12 && arr[2] >= 1 && arr[2] <= 31)
        return true;
}

function isValidTime(dateString) {
    var arr = dateString.split(':');
    if (arr[0].length = 2 && arr[0] >= 0 && arr[0] <= 12 && 
            arr[1].length == 2 && arr[1] >= 0 && arr[1] <= 59 && 
            arr[2].length == 2 && arr[2] >= 0 && arr[2] <= 59)
        return true;
}
app.directive('mimimi', function () {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('mimimi', false);
                    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (mimimi) {
                        mimimi = (mimimi.replace(',', "."));
                        if (isNumeric(mimimi))
                        {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('mimimi', true);
                            return mimimi;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('mimimi', false);
                            return undefined;
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        });
app.directive('lol', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('lol', false);
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (lol) {
                if (isValidDate(lol))
                {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('lol', true);
                    return lol;
                }
                else
                {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('lol', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
app.directive('time', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('time', false);
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (time) {
                if (isValidTime(time))
                {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('time', true);
                    return time;
                }
                else
                {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('time', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему тут вообще не нужны свои валидаторы/директивы, достаточно стандартных атрибутов инпута.

Похоже следующий вариант работает только для Chrome. Для остальных браузеров все-таки придется делать свои директивы.

```js
var app = angular.module('HelloHabr', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="HelloHabr">
  <form name="userForm">
    <div>
      <input class="form-control" numbers type="number" step="0.001" name="1st" ng-model="mimimi" required />
      <input class="form-control" type="date" name="2nd" ng-model="lol" required />
      <input class="form-control" type="time" name="3rd" ng-model="time" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
    <div>
      Number errors:
      <pre>{{userForm['1st'].$error | json}}</pre>
      Date errors:
      <pre>{{userForm['2nd'].$error | json}}</pre>
      Time errors:
      <pre>{{userForm['3rd'].$error | json}}</pre>
    </div>
  </form>
  <style>
    input.ng-valid {
      background-color: #81F7F3;
    }
    input.ng-invalid {
      background-color: #F78181;
    }
  </style>
</div>
```

Comment: несостоятельны, ибо не валидируют

Comment: @des1roer, у меня в приведенном сниппете все валидируют. С какими значениями возникают проблемы?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/AJrBlw8.png

Comment: @des1roer, как уже дописал в ответе - похоже работает только в хроме: и разделители в числах и контролы даты и времени

Comment: у меня как то страшно вышло. это можно нормально написать?

Comment: @des1roer, не совсем понял что именно проверяют `isValidDate` и `isValidTime`. И в каком формате в итоге должны вводится дата и время?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38689/discussion-between-grundy-and-des1roer).